# how to retrieve data from a form in the controller of an api rest in symfony

Tags: forms, rest, symfony, postman

I am registering a doctor in my api through my symfony controller. And for that I created a form for the doctor, and then I have to persist these data in my database. And that's where I can not get the data from the form, that's what I tried on my postman, but it returns me a 500 error saying:

> Child \"username\" does not exist.

I'm trying to recover my form data through this query:

> $user->setUsername($form['username']);

**Controller**

```
  /**
 * @Route("/api/inscription/medecin")
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_CREATED)
 * @Method("POST")
 */
   public function postDocAction(Request $request){

     $medecin = new Medecin();
    $user = new User();
    $user->setSalt('');
    $form = $this->createForm('Doctix\MedecinBundle\Form\MedecinType', $medecin);

    $form->submit($request->request->all()); // Validation des données

    if ($form->isValid()){
     $encoder = $this->get('security.password_encoder');
     $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
        $user->setPassword($encoded);
        $user->setUsername($form['username']);
        $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_MEDECIN'));

        $user->setNom($form['nom']);
        $user->setPrenom($form['prenom']);
        $user->setNumTel($form['numTel']);
        $user->setAdresse($form['adresse']);

        $medecin->setUser($user);
        $medecin->setSexe($form['sexe']);
        $medecin->setQuartier($form['quartier']);
        $medecin->setNumOrdre($form['numordre']);
        $medecin->setSpecialite($form['specialite']);
        $medecin->setClinique($form['clinique']);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($medecin);
        $em->flush();
  }
   }
```

**Form**

```
   class MedecinType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('user',UserType::class)
        ->add('sexe',  TextType::class)
        ->add('specialite',SpecialiteType::class)
        ->add('clinique',CliniqueType::class)
        ->add('quartier',  TextType::class)
        ->add('numordre',  TextType::class)
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin',
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ));
}
}
```

**Test in Postman**

[image: registertest]

Answer (score 0):

After you do `$form->handleRequest($request);`,
`$form->getData()` holds the submitted values.

But, the original `$medecin` variable has also been updated. So non need to set all the fields again.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Comment: Hi @Zak, i hadn't use $form->handleRequest($request); but $form->submit($request->request->all()); for data validation.

Answer (score 0):

**short answer :**
According to the json, user seems to be an object so to access `username`, you should probably write:

> $form["user"]["username"];
>   You should apply the same logic to all elements inside user.

**complete answer :**
There are multiple incoherences in your code. The advantage of passing the object into the createForm() method, is that the object will automaticaly be updated once the form is submited and valid. This avoid you to go throught all the setters later as you are doing now.

So if you want the user object to be correcly updated into the medecin's object, you should set the user before creating the form :

```php
<?php
 /**
 * @Route("/api/inscription/medecin")
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_CREATED)
 * @Method("POST")
 */
 public function postDocAction(Request $request){

    $medecin = new Medecin();
    $user = new User();
    $user->setSalt('');
    $user->setRoles(['ROLE_MEDECIN']);
    $medecin->setUser($user);

    $form = $this->createForm('Doctix\MedecinBundle\Form\MedecinType', $medecin);
    $form->submit($request->request->all()); // Validation des données

    if ($form->isValid()) {
     $encoder = $this->get('security.password_encoder');
     $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
     $user->setPassword($encoded);

     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

     $em->persist($user); // Safety, as i don't know how you configured your entities
     $em->persist($medecin);
     $em->flush();
   }
 }
```